# How do I subset my SOTU dfm to Presidents Wilson and later in quanteda?

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I'm working with quanteda.corpora's SOTU corpus and need to subset it to look at roughly the last century of SOTU speeches. I'm coming from tm though, so I'm not super familiar with managing dfm objects.

I've learned how to preprocess the corpus when in dfm format, but I'm not certain what to do next. This is what I have right now. To my understanding, this code ought to subset my corpus to include only documents that were delivered after 1913.

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.corpora)
dfmat_sotu <- dfm(data_corpus_sotu, tolower = TRUE, remove = stopwords("english"), remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE)
dfmat_sotu <- dfm_wordstem(dfmat_sotu, language = quanteda_options("language_stemmer"))
dfmat_sotu <- dfm_subset(dfmat_sotu, Date > 1913-12-02)
wf_sotu <- textmodel_wordfish(dfmat_sotu)

textplot_scale1d(wf_sotu)
```

The issue is that when I run this code as well as wordfish, it becomes clear that I haven't subset the corpus as intended -- it seems to only include speeches from 1978 and later. What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Thank you for the question. We have detailed tutorials online. https://tutorials.quanteda.io/basic-operations/dfm/ You could follow from here. And the answer to your question is `dfm_subset()` or `dfm_select()` depending on whether you want to select documents or features respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've taken your suggestion and attempted to use `dfm_subset()` to restrict my corpus to the desired documents. It's not working, however -- I assume due to the way that dates are formatted in the corpus metadata?

Comment: Well. You need to make your date condition as a date object. Do `dfm_subset(dfmat_sotu, Date > as.Date("1913-12-02"))` instead.